# Remote method for updating all records

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I try to make a custom endpoint, which adds a bonus to **all** employee. And retorns all the employee records, just like the get endpoint.
Something like `/employees/bonus`

As I understand; I should make a remote method for this:

**common/models/employee.js**

```
Employee.bonus = function(cb){
  // logic comes here
  cb(null,"")
}

Employee.remoteMethod(
  'bonus',{}
)
```

This makes the endpoint, but how can request all the employees, to loop them through and increase their salary property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query your Employee model, apply filter if you need, then loop through results.

```
Employee.find(
  filter, 
  function(err,employees) {
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
    employees.forEach(
      function(employee){
         fnIncSalary(employee.salary);
        //do something with employee instance
      }
    );
  }
);
```

http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Querying+data